# Bunder require yaml/logger

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am using bundler to require all the gems in my project. However, it's not working for yaml/logger.

If I add gem 'yaml' to my gemfile, and run bundle install, I get:

```
Could not find gem 'yaml (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

But I require it normally just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`YAML` is part of the [Ruby Standard Library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html), and not a Gem.

You do not need to add it to your Gemfile, just require it.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> YAML
=> Psych
```

The same applies for [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/logger/rdoc/index.html).